# How to recursively search for string term in a list of obects

Tags: c#, algorithm, search

I'm trying to implement a way of searching a list of objects for some search term and then returning those objects.

So far, I have managed to get it working if the search term is contained in any of the object's string properties:

#### IEnumerableExtensions

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string search)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        items = items.Where(i => i.Contains(search));

    return items;
}
```

#### ObjectExtensions

```
public static bool Contains(this object inuputObject, string word)
{
    return inuputObject.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            .Select(x => (string)x.GetValue(inuputObject, null))
            .Where(x => x != null)
            .Any(x => x.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
}
```

The problem is, the objects I'm searching each contain a list of `user` objects, and I want **to include the string properties of those users** in my search.

I tried this:

```
public static bool Contains(this object inuputObject, string word)
{
    var result = false;

    var type = inuputObject.GetType();
    var properties = type.GetProperties();

    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property != null)
        {
            var propertyValue = (string)property.GetValue(inuputObject, null);
            result = propertyValue.IndexOf(word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
        }
        else
        {
            result = property.Contains(word);
        }

        if (result)
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I think this is iterating around properties which I'm not interested in, and it causes the program to crash with this message in VS:

> **The application is in break mode**
>
> Your app has entered a break state, but there is no code to show because all threads were executing external code (typically system or framework code).

I've never seen such an error before, but I suspect it has something to do with the code running into an infinite loop, as it is checking the properties of the object, then the properties of those properties etc etc - where would that stop?

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can achieve this?

Thank you

Comment: I don't think this `property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property != null` is doing what you think it is.

Comment: Right, that doesn't make any sense. If the property were null then accessing its type would have already crashed.

Comment: That aside, you know that what you're doing is *super dangerous*, right?  You're randomly invoking properties that happen to return strings and hoping that they don't have dangerous side effects. And what happens if you have two properties that refer to each other? For example, you have a type with a property `Mother` and a type with a property `Daughter` and you end up bouncing back and forth between them forever.

Comment: @EricLippert No I did not know that. Do you have any suggestions for a better way of doing this? Maybe I should give up on trying to make it generic?

Comment: The way you fix that is of course *remember where you've been*, but that "fixes" the problem by consuming arbitrarily much memory.

Comment: This should be flipped but this will not fix your issue: `property.PropertyType == typeof(string) && property != null`. Check if not null first and then do the next check.

Comment: Microsoft's [ObjectDumper](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/MSDN-108-C-LINQ-Samples-52207c43/sourcecode?fileId=108854&pathId=1317055433) sample shows up all over the place.

Comment: @Brian That does look interesting, but it seems like overkill, as some of the values sent to `Writer` are things like `=` or `"  "` or the name of a property - all things which I would not want my search to return.

Comment: @Bassie: You'd use that code as a starting point, not as-is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution looks like this

#### ObjectExtensions.cs

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks each string property of the given object to check if it contains the 
    /// search term. If any of those properties is a collection, we search that 
    /// collection using the the IEnumarableExtensions Search
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="inputObject"></param>
    /// <param name="term"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool Contains(this object inputObject, string term)
    {
        var result = false;

        if (inputObject == null)
            return result;

        var properties = inputObject
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // First check if the object is a string (and ensure it is not null)
            if (property != null && property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                var propertyValue = (string)property.GetValue(inputObject, null);
                result = propertyValue == null
                    ? false
                    : propertyValue.IndexOf(term, 
                        StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;
            }
            // Otherwise, check if its a collection (we need to do this after the string  
            // check, as a string is technically a IEnumerable type
            else if (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                result = ((IEnumerable<object>)property
                    .GetValue(inputObject, null))
                    .Search(term).Count() > 0;
            }
            else
            {
                var propertyValue = property.GetValue(inputObject, null);
                result = propertyValue == null
                    ? false
                    : propertyValue.ToString().Contains(term);
            }

            if (result)
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

#### IEnumerableExtensions.cs

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension method that searches a list of generic objects' string properties 
    /// for the given search term using the 'Contains' object extension
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="items"></param>
    /// <param name="search"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<T> Search<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string search)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
            items = items.Where(i => i.Contains(search));

        return items;
    }
}
```

#### Usage

So to search a collection of objects for some string:

```
var list = new List<MyType>(){};
var results = list.Search("searchTerm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive call checks if the `property` object contains the `word`, not if the value of that property on your original object contains the word.

Change

```
result = property.Contains(word);
```

to

```
result = property.GetValue(inuputObject, null).Contains(word);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip NetMage. I added an answer with my final solution if you were interested